# Setting max number of lines in Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML:

```
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="archive in archives" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1"><b>{{extractDomain(archive.url)}}</b></h5>
        </div>
            <p class="mb-1">{{archive.headline}}</p>
            <p class="pv-archiveText">{{archive.text}}</p>
    </a>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.pv-archiveText {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: red;
}
```

I'm seeing the text as red, but it's not being limited to one line. I tried

```
{
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: N; /* number of lines to show */
   line-height: X;        /* fallback */
   max-height: X*N;       /* fallback */
}
```

and multiple other styles, but none of them are working. Is it because of the Bootstrap/Angular?

Comment: You need to use [white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) if you don't want your text to wrap (otherwise the overflow never happens).

Comment: @TiesonT. Thank you, that did it

Comment: I would suggest adding a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the style worked: `white-space: nowrap`. As noted in the MDN for [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Collapses whitespace as for `normal`, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

For example:

```css
.pv-archiveText {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p class="pv-archiveText">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ligula libero, interdum id risus bibendum, sagittis ultrices est. Suspendisse elit felis, finibus eget rutrum eget, ultricies nec odio. Suspendisse ut nisl sit amet quam mattis dapibus. Praesent auctor hendrerit elit sed hendrerit.
</p>
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to add an example of how the style works to your answer. I've added a Stack Snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is always on one line you can try

```
.pv-archiveText {
  height: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto
}
```